# Drawing decoded bitmaps to ImageView from Android doc

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I was having a problem where my bitmaps were causing my application to skip frames at a rapid rate. I have looked into android's "Displaying Bitmap's Efficiently" documentation, and have implemented some into my code.

I am pretty sure the image is loading correctly, but its not showing in my application. The height and width of the image view is 0 after I do this decoding, so this might be one of the reasons, but I can't change the size of the ImageView for some reason.

BitmapWorkerTask.java:

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
private int data = 0;

private Context context;

public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView, Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
    imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
}

// Decode image in background.
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    data = params[0];
    System.out.println("T" + buildBitmap(data, 100, 100));
    return buildBitmap(data, 100, 100);
}

// Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (isCancelled()) {
        bitmap = null;
    }

    if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
        final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
        final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask =
                AsyncDrawable.getBitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
        if (this == bitmapWorkerTask && imageView != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}

public Bitmap buildBitmap(int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resId, options);
}

public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if(height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}


static class AsyncDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
    private final WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask> bitmapWorkerTaskReference;

    public AsyncDrawable(Resources res, Bitmap bitmap, BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask) {
        super(res, bitmap);
        bitmapWorkerTaskReference = new WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask>(bitmapWorkerTask);
    }

    public BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWorkerTask() {
        return bitmapWorkerTaskReference.get();
    }

    public static boolean cancelPotentialWork(int data, ImageView imageView) {
        final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = getBitmapWorkerTask(imageView);

        if (bitmapWorkerTask != null) {
            final int bitmapData = bitmapWorkerTask.data;
            // If bitmapData is not yet set or it differs from the new data
            if (bitmapData == 0 || bitmapData != data) {
                // Cancel previous task
                bitmapWorkerTask.cancel(true);
            } else {
                // The same work is already in progress
                return false;
            }
        }
        // No task associated with the ImageView, or an existing task was cancelled
        return true;
    }

    private static BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
           if (imageView != null) {
               final Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
               if (drawable instanceof AsyncDrawable) {
                   final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = (AsyncDrawable) drawable;
                   return asyncDrawable.getBitmapWorkerTask();
               }
            }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

I am creating the image in the constructor of my View class, and then drawing the TextView in the onDraw method.

```
public Game(Context context) {

    loadBitmap(R.drawable.logo, scoreHolderView);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    if(STATE == State.Playing) {

        synchronized(spawner.activeTiles) {
            for(Iterator<Tile> iter = spawner.activeTiles.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                Tile tile = iter.next();
                canvas.drawRect(tile, tile.getColor());
            }
        }

        //canvas.drawBitmap(scoreholder, null, scoreIcon, null);

        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(SCORE), 50, 50, blackText);
        scoreHolderView.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Is the position and size of the ImageView just not being set for some reason? Or are there other problems with my code?

EDIT:

```
public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView) {
    if (AsyncDrawable.cancelPotentialWork(resId, imageView)) {
        final BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView, getContext());
        final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable =
                new AsyncDrawable(getResources(), logo, task);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(asyncDrawable);
        task.execute(resId);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `buildBitmap()` twice. A waste of resources.

Comment: I nowhere see an execute() call for an BitmapWorkerTask instance. How does this work?

Comment: Oops 1 sec I forgot a piece of cope

Comment: And Im only calling it twice because I was testing something..

Comment: Now please explain what this code all should do. Why do you need so much code to put a Bitmap in an ImageView? Why do you need an AsyncDrawable? LoadBitmap called by Game. But what is Game? What does it have to do with onDraw? Where is this all about?

Comment: As I said Im just following this guide: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: And its not working, im not really sure why I need all this code but apparently loading a bitmap the easy way causes my application to skip 200 frames at a time

Comment: `but apparently loading a bitmap the easy way causes my application to skip 200 frames at a time –` ??? You are doing it in a difficult way to begin with.

Comment: You could better read some stackoverflow pages with tag android as putting a picture in an image view can be done with a few lines of code.

Comment: Do you not think I have tried this? I would not have gone to these crazy lengths for nothing. I tried the easy methods but my application would lag

Comment: Everything that makes sense doesnt work so thats why I tried following android's documentation